# Javascript Canvas - Circles are changing color

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am having a problem with drawing circles on a canvas. When I draw a circle on my canvas it works fine, but if I draw a square afterwards, the color of my circle changes to the same color as the square.

This has been troubling me for a while now. Here is a jsbin project to demonstrate what I am talking about:

```
https://jsbin.com/bajezudayi/edit?html,js,output
```

On this canvas you can draw circles and squares (note the check box at the top to switch shapes).

I have tried changing the color variable in the drawCircle to a set value instead of being a function argument but the problem persists.

```
function drawCircle(x,y,rad,col,ctx){
  // This function draws a circle on a canvas
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x,y);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0,0,rad,0,2*Math.PI,false);
    ctx.fillStyle='red'; // rather than =col
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

If I apply an animation loop to my canvas, even weirder effects start to happen because of this issue.

Any ideas why this is happening?
Thank you.

Edit:
Here is the full project I am currently working on:

http://adam-day-com.stackstaging.com/orbital/index.html

Try checking the 'show vector field' box and add some planets. The function to draw the vector field (called in an animation loop) draws a series of thin boxes and it messes up the circle colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `ctx.beginPath()` and `ctx.closePath()` and things seem to working fine. Is this what you wanted? https://jsbin.com/ribiyodoru/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you. This did work for the jsbin project I shared with you, but it is not working with my main project. You can check it out in my edit to the question. Thank you for your help. it is a start in the right direction. I will keep trying.

Comment: @AdamDay I still don't see closePath being used here? http://adam-day-com.stackstaging.com/Orbital/js/drawArrow.js and http://adam-day-com.stackstaging.com/Orbital/js/drawCircle.js

Comment: Sorry I am working on this locally and then uploading to a webhosting service. I forgot to update the file on the server. It should be good now

Comment: I solved it. My function drawSquare (or drawArrow if youre looking at my full project) called ctx.fill() after already filling the rectangle. I guess ctx.fill() applied the color to the last drawn circle. Everything is working now. Thank you for your help.